# Display a specific field value based on a dropdown list field

Tags: database, field, filemaker

we are working here with filemaker and i'm getting arround to make it work for my need.

Here are the field i have
Field name "For this year" is a drop down list with a list of 10 year manually updated when needed
Every year have a field name "Price 2020", "Price 2021", Price 2022" etc.

I want to moved the value of the field "Price 2020" when i select the option "2020" in the drop down menu of the field "For this year" and the "Price 2021" when i select the option "2021", and etc.
This value need to be copied in another field named "Price for the selected year"

If not too much, i also want to copy the field of the "Price (year - 1)" in a field named "Price for the year before"

I tried looking arround the web, but i can't find what to ask on google to find some case that look like what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is difficult to follow, but this part caught my eye:

> Every year have a field name "Price 2020", "Price 2021", Price 2022" etc.

That's not a good structure. You should have a **table** of Prices, where each price is an individual **record** with fields for (at minimum) Year and Price. Then, when you select a year in your current table (not sure of what), you can lookup the price for the selected year using a **relationship** matching on year.

Comment: P.S. Stack Overflow is strictly a question-and-answer site. I recommend you join one of the forums dedicated to the Filemaker  platform, where you can get more detailed help.

Comment: Hi Michael, this could be an option, but every record on the main table have a different price value for each year. So i would need a table for each main record, we have over a thousand client on the main table.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know what is a "main table". In a situation where you have a table of Products, and each product has a different price for every year (or for every color, or for every client, or every whatever), it is standard to have a PriceList table where each price is an individual record.